# How to change bigcommerce featured products to random products

Tags: widget, bigcommerce

I have a bigcommerce account, and in home html there are only 3 options to display products  featured, new, and most popular
Now, instead of featured products I want to display random products, so every person after entering the website or refreshing it can see different products
Is there any way I can do that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpYeN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this is by creating a custom widget which uses GraphQL to fetch products. You could get an idea of the total number of products in the system and then fetch them at random via [GQL](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/graphql-storefront/reference#definition-SearchProducts). This feature isn't native to BigCommerce though.